# Subscribing users directly to a mailing list without confirmation

Tags: python, email, newsletter, mailchimp, campaign-monitor

I wrote a simple email service that uses jinja2 templates (as the body) and SMTP to send emails when a user first logs into our Flask application. In that html email I want to include a URL that will go to a landing page that says 'You have been subscribed to our newsletter.' I have been looking at MailChimp, Campaign Monitor and Aweber to handle the newsletter tasks. All the above mentioned services allow users to be directly added to a list without filling a sign-up form. I have looked at the mailchimp API to see if I can override their default opt-in process which I can.

So my question is:

1) Is there any way I can directly add users to a subscription list without having them to fill out any information using the above services?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Campaign Monitors](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/subscribers/#adding_a_subscriber) API. Is there a reason the API is not ideal? Otherwise it seems you answered your own question in the question...

In automating the process, obviously you still need their email address. If you are still after some subscriber confirmation this might be an option:

ESP's all supply the form code you can place on your own page/website. You could easily link to the page with a URL parameter like so:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/signup.php?Email=subscriber@theiremail.com">Sign Up</a>
```

The idea is to prefill the form with the email address (and any other info) by passing as a URL parameter. All the subscriber would have to do is hit enter to confirm.

Comment: So if I use campaign monitor or mailchimp - I will use the link that they provide for the sign-up form and pre-fill the fields by passing the values as params? Can I ensure that the users won't receive another email that asks them to confirm their subscription (double-optin?)?

Comment: Not that straight forward. You'd need to put in the page a little bit of PHP to get it to fill the formfield. Whether a subscriber receives an email signup confirmation is completely up to your opt-in settings in Campaign Monitor/Mailchimp. Just deselect 'Double Opt-in' for your list and their 'paste in your own website' forms will work without confirmation, with or without the pre-filling via URL. Prefilling is just to save them typing in their email address if you already know who they are